# What is wrong here - doesn't print correct record

Tags: awk

What is wrong here ?

Based on this example;

```
ls -l | awk 'BEGIN {max = 0; rec=""} {if ($5>max) max=$5; rec=$0} END {print max "\n" rec}'
```

max prints the size of the largest file, but rec doesn't print the corresponding record, but just the last one passed.
I would expect that rec contains the full record of the largest file.

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: No idea why it's off-topic. But it was very useful for me.

Comment: Yep, why is this offtopic..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($5>max) max=$5; rec=$0
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if ($5>max) {
  max=$5;
}
rec=$0
```

Which sets `rec` unconditionally.

You need:

```
if ($5>max) { max=$5; rec=$0 }
```

Comment: Accepted this one as answer because of the additional explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
if ($5>max) max=$5; rec=$0
```

to:

```
if ($5>max) { max=$5; rec=$0 }
```